# EF Core ignoring condition when extracted in method

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

After extracting a simple Linq2Entity condition on an IQueryable from

```
orders = orders.Where(o => o.AddressId.HasValue && _validAddressIds.Contains(o.AddressId.Value));
```

to a methode like so:

```
orders = orders.Where(o => IsValidAddress(o.AddressId));

...

private bool IsValidAddress(long addressId)
{
  return adressId.HasValue && _validAddressIds.Contains(addressId);
}
```

the condition is not contained in the generated SQL anymore, it gets applied in memory only. Why is that???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to use an expression like so:

```
public Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetFilteredAddressExpression<T>() where T : IAddress
{
    return x => x.AddressId != null && _validAddressIds.Contains(x.AddressId.Value);
}
```